# Buildozer выдает ошибку при попытке скачиваний python 3.10.10.tgz

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

При попытке сборки apk buildozer выдает ошибку а именно при попытке скачать hostpython3. Я скачал пакет вручную и поместил в директорию `*/home/user/Desktop/app/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/packages/hostpython3/`. Но buildozer его удаляет и пытается скачать заново. Есть ли способ обойти эту загрузку?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте скачать более ранюю версию питона а также проверьте версии которые подерживает библиотека питон

Comment: Пробовал ошибка таже не изменилась